# Cant register gitlab runner from script?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to automate the registration of runners, which run on local docker environment, using a script. The scripts runs the registration non-interactively as follows:

```
gitlab-runner -l debug register --non-interactive --url $GITLAB_URL --registration-token $TOEKN \
  --executor docker --docker-image python3 --name TestRunner --docker-pull-policy always \
  --locked=false --run-untagged=false --docker-privileged=false \
  --limit 0 \
  --tag-list general,test
```

I still couldn't register the runner using this script while doing it interactively completes successfully. The error I get when registering the runner using the command above:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=57 revision=05161b14 version=12.4.1
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=linux uid=0
Running in system-mode.                            

Dialing: tcp gitlab.com:443 ...                    
ERROR: Registering runner... forbidden (check registration token)  runner=--execut
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

What is the difference that causes the registration to fail when using a non-interactive script instead of the interactive method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was reading the registration token variable itself. So, by first reading it into a quoted variable it becomes usable:

```
t="$TOKEN"
gitlab-runner -l debug register --non-interactive --url ${GITLAB_URL} --registration-token ${t} \
  --executor docker --docker-image python3 --name TestRunner --docker-pull-policy always \
  --locked=false --run-untagged=false --docker-privileged=false \
  --limit 0 \
  --tag-list general,test
```